# How to return html data from a .txt file using python?

Tags: python, html, printing, extract

I want to build a program that extracts certain parts of a websites html source code. the html has been inserted in a .txt file to pull from. Can I used built in functions in Python to achieve this? If not define a function that would do this. These are just two lines of code.

I want to extract = `"usage":"188,426 mi"` found in line 2 at the very start about index 88.

```html
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"><div class="sr_grid_tile sr_item "><div class="sr_photo sr_grid_photo" id="srt_10487726"><div class="sr_ica sr_ica_trucks"><span class="screen-reader-txt">With IronClad Assurance</span></div><div class="sr_quickview" onclick="showQuickview(10487726,0);"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showQuickview(10487726,0);">Quick View</a></div><div class="sr_photo_container sr_photo_grid_container"><a href="/for-sale/Pickup-Trucks-2018-Ford-F-150-Lariat-4x4-Crew-Cab-Pickup-Florida/10487726?h=5000%2Csm%7C1%2Ck%7CFord+F-150%2Cmf%7C1&rr=1&hitprm=&pnLink=yes" onclick="return checkLoggedIn(this, '/for-sale/Pickup-Trucks-2018-Ford-F-150-Lariat-4x4-Crew-Cab-Pickup-Florida/10487726?h=5000%2Csm%7C1%2Ck%7CFord+F-150%2Cmf%7C1&rr=1&hitprm=&pnLink=yes');" itemprop="url"><img alt="2018&#x20;Ford&#x20;F-150&#x20;Lariat&#x20;4x4&#x20;Crew&#x20;Cab&#x20;Pickup" title="2018&#x20;Ford&#x20;F-150&#x20;Lariat&#x20;4x4&#x20;Crew&#x20;Cab&#x20;Pickup" id="sr_img_10487726" data-original="https://cdn.ironpla.net/i/14164/202/093fb57e-1110-43b9-8b4a-2b573292cb4e-nowater.jpg" itemprop="image"></a></div></div><div class="sr_grid_details"><div class="sr_equip_desc sr_grid_equip_desc"><a href="/for-sale/Pickup-Trucks-2018-Ford-F-150-Lariat-4x4-Crew-Cab-Pickup-Florida/10487726?h=5000%2Csm%7C1%2Ck%7CFord+F-150%2Cmf%7C1&rr=1&hitprm=&pnLink=yes" onclick="return checkLoggedIn(this, '/for-sale/Pickup-Trucks-2018-Ford-F-150-Lariat-4x4-Crew-Cab-Pickup-Florida/10487726?h=5000%2Csm%7C1%2Ck%7CFord+F-150%2Cmf%7C1&rr=1&hitprm=&pnLink=yes');"><span itemprop="name">2018 Ford F-150 Lariat 4x4 Crew Cab Pickup</span></a></div><div class="sr_meter">Meter: <span class="meter_reading">188,426 mi</span></div><div class="sr_location"><span class="flag flag-USA"><img src="/k_images/cntry_flag/all-flags.png" role="presentation" alt=""></span>&nbsp;Florida<div class="sr_distance_away">(1,122 mi away)</div></div><div class="sr_grid_auc_info"><div style="border-top:1px dotted #ccc;margin-left: 38px"></div><div class="sr_bf"><div class='sr_bf_icon sr_bf_icon_grid'><img src='/n_images/TP-icon.png' role='presentation' alt=''></div><div class="sr_bf_qv sr_bf_ol sr_bf_grid">Online Auction</div></div><div class="sr_price"><span class="price"><span itemprop="price">US $14,100</span></span></div><div style="padding:5px 0">Sep 14 2023</div><div style="overflow: hidden;"></div></div><div style="padding: 5px 0 0"></div><div class="sr_compare"><input type="checkbox" id="ci_10487726" name="ci_10487726" onclick="itemToCompare(event,this)"><label for="ci_10487726">&nbsp;Compare</label>&nbsp;<input type="button" onclick="doCompareItems(event);" value="Compare"></div></div></div></div>
  <script>quickviews.push({"isICA":true,"flagPath":"USA","bidUrl":"javascript:void(0);","usage":"188,426 mi","distanceString":"(1,122 mi away)","description":"2018 Ford F-150 Lariat 4x4 Crew Cab Pickup","convPrice":"US $14,100","registrationNu":"1049007","meterReadingDisplay":true,"itemPageUri":"/for-sale/Pickup-Trucks-2018-Ford-F-150-Lariat-4x4-Crew-Cab-Pickup-Florida/10487726?h=5000%2Csm%7C1%2Ck%7CFord+F-150%2Cmf%7C1&rr=1&hitprm=&pnLink=yes","resvMet":"","catalogNotes":"","ucaEnabled":false,"features":"2.7 L V6 Gasoline Engine, 2018 US EPA Label, Automatic Transmission, Air Conditioner, Power Driver's Seat, Power Adjustable Pedals, Power Windows, Power Sliding Rear Window, Spray-On Bed Liner, 7000.0 lb GVWR, 275/70R18 Tires, 5 ft 6 in Bed","externalSite":false,"price":"Sold for <span class=\"price\"><span itemprop=\"price\">US $14,100<\/span><\/span>","eumeLocation":"Florida","photoThumb":"https://cdn.ironpla.net/i/14164/202/093fb57e-1110-43b9-8b4a-2b573292cb4e-small.jpg","currency":"USD","auctionType":"<div><div class='sr_bf_icon'><img src='/n_images/TP-icon.png' role='presentation' alt=''><\/div><div class=\"sr_bf_qv sr_bf_ol\">Online Auction<\/div><\/div>","bidCnt":"","noPhoto":false,"lat":27.9256,"vmImages":"","equipId":"10487726","itemRealmId":21,"photoBigger":"https://cdn.ironpla.net/i/14164/202/093fb57e-1110-43b9-8b4a-2b573292cb4e-full.jpg","lng":-82.3736,"marketplace":"T","inspLabel":"Inspection Details","photo":"https://cdn.ironpla.net/i/14164/202/093fb57e-1110-43b9-8b4a-2b573292cb4e-nowater.jpg","usageLabel":"Meter:","equipStatus":65});precheckCompare(quickviews.length-1,10487726);</script>
```

```py
typtruck_usage_index=[]  #called a list 
with (open('first_truck_source.txt', 'rt') as source): #used the open function to draw from my .txt
    for truck_usage_index in source: #for loop for ever line
        seperate = truck_usage_index.split() #use the split method to break up the line into list
        print(seperate) #using the seperate variable we print the list broken up by python
        position = truck_usage_index.find('"usage":') #use find method to find the index of "usage":
        print(position) #prints the index of the (") which is 88
```

How to I get it to print the entire information which in this case would be. `"usage":"188,426 mi"`

Answer (score 1):

Everything between `quickviews.push(` and `);precheckCompare` can be parsed as JSON. So search for this line, extract what you want, and use `json.loads()` to parse it into a dictionary. Then you can get the `usage` value.

```
import re, json

with open('first_truck_source.txt', 'rt') as source:
    for line in source:
        if m := re.search(r'quickviews\.push\((.*?)\);precheckCompare', line):
            data = json.loads(m.group(1))
            usage = data['usage']
            print(usage)
```